# Paypal Recurring payment API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, recurring

Need a simple tutorial for Paypal Recurring payment using the latest REST API. On Dev site of paypal there is no such explanation for that.

Answer (score 2):

"Recurring Payments" are referred to as "Billing Plans" in the documentation for REST API. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/

Comment: Thank You, I checked above documentation, but unable to understand from where i will start, old code/documentation is clear and to the point, but it was deprecated, don't want to take risk, Can you share some code examples, how to proceed with new one?